# Getting auto-complete in VSCode for JSX attribute values of 3rd parties

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I started using [react-native-animatable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable). It is similar to [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) with many pre-defined animations for React Native. Remembering all the different animation names is tricky, how do I set auto-complete in VSCode for the different animation names:

[image: autocomplete]

The project has a [definition file](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable/blob/master/typings/react-native-animatable.d.ts). I am not working with Typescript but I guess auto-completion wouldn't mind, right? How do I set it up?

What I've tried so far:

I've added a file named tsconfig.json in the root:

```
{
    "allowJs": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": ["typings/react-native-animatable.d"]
}
```

I have copied the 3rd party's definition to a directory named "typings".

Still no luck.

Comment: Since the project has a definition file, you should not need to create that tsconfig file. Do you get intellisense for the attribute names? How are you importing `Animatable` in your code?

Comment: I'm using import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure typings definition files end in `.d.ts` While I'm not sure what the exact problem or solution is [this page - under the 'quick fix' heading](https://johnpapa.net/intellisense-witha-visual-studio-code/) may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in 16.11 react but by pasting three files in react folder in node_modules: which are index.d.ts and experimental.d.ts and global.d.ts. I got these from my old project which is 16.9 react.